# Find a holomorphic function when you know the real part.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying again to learn complex analysys and I have solved an exercise in here but I am not sure if it is correct.
$u(x,y) = x^2-y^2+ln(x^2+y^2)$. I need to find $f$ holomorphic function, such that $Re(f) = u$
 This is how I tried to solved it:
 $f = u+iv$. Since $f$ is a holomorphic function it needs to satisfy the
Cauchy–Riemann equations:
 $\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\ 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{matrix}\right.$
 $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x+\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \Rightarrow v = \int 2x+\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}dx$ 
Therefore, $f = x^2-y^2+ln(x^2+y^2)+iv$, right?

Comment: In fact, $$v_y=2x+\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}\implies v=\int\left(2x+\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}\right)\,d\color{red}y$$

Comment: In your fomula, you should be integrating over $y$ instead of $x$. Then you get an expression for $v$ up to a constant depending on $x$. Now, use the second Cauchy-Riemann equation to say something about this constant.

Comment: There is no such function unless you restrict the domain.

Comment: $f(z)=z^{2}+\frac 1 2 \log z$ is such a function if you remove a half line from the plane and use an analytic branch of logarithm. But on the whole complex plane such a  function $f$ does not exist.

Comment: @DonAntonio, yeah right, which is $v = ln |y^2+x^2|+C|$. Now i've tried to get C from second Cauchy-Riemann equation but not quite sure how to do it. I mean, from the second equation I got $v = -2arctan( \frac{x}{y})+2xy+C $

Comment: Well, now you must get $\;u_y=-v_x\;$ ,right? And observe that $\;C\;$ is constant **with respecto to** $\;y\;$ only, not necessarily wrt $\;x\;$ ...

Comment: I'm not quite sure, sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$v=2xy+2\arctan\frac yx+C(x)\implies v_x=2y-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}+C'(x)$$

and this must equal

$$-u_y=2y-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}\stackrel{\text{comparing with above}}\implies C'(x)=0\implies C(x)=K\;(=\text{constant})$$

so

$$v=2xy+2\arctan\frac yx+K\,,\,\,\;K=\text{constant}$$